# Calculating daily maximum displacement of an animal

Tags: r, gps

I'm quite new in R and would need some help.
I have animal movement data with the following columns: "`TagID`", "`Date`", "`location.long`", "`location.lat`"

I need to find *the **distance between the consecutive GPS points** separately for each day* and *for each individual*. After that, I'm trying to find the **maximum displacemen**t for that day which means the distance between the first point of the day and the farthest point of this animal for the same day.

Here is the ***data structure***:

```
    TagID   Date      location.long location.lat
1   6634 2018-10-22     10.311283     48.20341
2   6634 2018-10-22     10.319261     48.18381
3   6634 2018-10-22     10.321538     48.15845
4   6634 2018-10-22     10.293819     48.15497
5   6634 2018-10-22     10.369189     48.12718
6   6634 2018-10-22     10.333642     48.14402
7   6634 2018-10-23     10.256952     48.12419
8   6634 2018-10-23     10.283222     48.11557
9   6634 2018-10-23     10.264805     48.10601
10  6634 2018-10-23     10.358082     48.07012
11  6634 2018-10-23     10.310423     48.03421
12  6678 2018-10-22      9.981601     48.24799
13  6678 2018-10-22      9.999586     48.22714
14  6678 2018-10-22      9.963930     48.29394
15  6678 2018-10-22      9.989562     48.17918
```

Up to now I have reached to this point:

```
mydata <- read.csv("tracking.csv")
onlcoor <- subset (mydata, select = c("location.long","location.lat"))
m <- as.matrix(onlcoor)
#Creates a matrix witht the distances between each point in the dataset
mydata$dist <- distm(m, fun=distVincentyEllipsoid)
#Returns the maximum distance between the first point the farthest from it
mydata$displacement <- max(mydata$dist[,1])
```

It calculates the distance between the consecutive points and returns the displacement (distance between the first and farthest point from it).

Now, I would like to add two conditions into the code

1. TagID isn't considered. Therefore, a distance for the last location of an animal will be generated using the first location of a new animal when the distance should be NA.
2. The Date should be taken into account as well because I need the maximum daily displacement of each individual

**Here is the code which finally worked for me:**

```
mydata <- read.csv("tracking.csv")    
mydata <- split(mydata, list(mydata$TagID, mydata$Date), drop = TRUE)
displacem <- sapply(mydata, function(mydata){
     onlcoor <- subset (mydata, select = 
c("location.long","location.lat"))
     m <- as.matrix(onlcoor)
     mydata$dist <- distm(m, fun=distVincentyEllipsoid)
     mydata$displ <- max(mydata$dist[,1]) 
   })
write.table(displacem, file = "maximum_displacement.csv",row.names=FALSE, 
na="",col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

Comment: I would approach this in the following manner. First, I would make a function that would take in a data.frame and return the distance you are after (what you have so far). Then, I would translate the date to Y-m-d format (discard time). Then, I would split the data by TagID and this new date. This way, each chunk would have your desired subset of TagID-day. Apply the above function to this subset and you're done. You can use function `split` and `lapply` (or `sapply` if you feel daring :) ).

Comment: Note that there are heaps of package dealing with (animal) movement. See [CRAN Task View: Handling and Analyzing Spatio-Temporal Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/SpatioTemporal.html), and e.g. [adehabitatLT: Analysis of Animal Movements](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adehabitatLT/index.html). Good luck!

Comment: You may also consider to provide sufficiently complex toy data - because you want to calculate movement per animal and day, it would be nice if you had 3-4 positions per day for two animals. Cheers.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks for the hint! lapply seems to be a very useful function.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I transformed the date format as you suggested. Then splited the data by TagID and Date and tried to calculate the distances between the points within the chunks. It seems to be working and the matrix with the distances between each point is properly created. However, when i try to get the maximum displacement it returns the same value for each three sets. What did i do wrong? I added the script i wrote as edit to the question